How can I show a loader while a form is rendering in Vue 3?
I'm using Vue 3 with the Composition API. I have a TabView component with multiple TabPanel components, and each tab contains a form that takes a few seconds(3-4 seconds) to render. I want to show a loader while the form is rendering. Since the form rendering is not promise-based, I'm having trouble getting the loader to display correctly.
Here is the simplified code:
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="loading">Loading...</p>
    <TabView @tabChange="handleTabChange">
      <TabPanel v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
        <template #header>{{ tab.label }}</template>
        <div v-if="currentTab === index && !loading">
          <FormKit :data="tab.formData" />
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabView>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, nextTick, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import TabView from './components/TabView.vue';
import TabPanel from './components/TabPanel.vue';
import FormComponent from './components/FormComponent.vue';

const tabs = ref([
  { label: 'Tab 1', formData: { /* form data */ } },
  { label: 'Tab 2', formData: { /* form data */ } },
  // Add more tabs as needed
]);

const loading = ref(false);
const currentTab = ref(0);

const handleTabChange = async (index: number) => {
  loading.value = true;
  currentTab.value = index;

  await nextTick();
  loading.value = false;
};

</script>


Problem:
The loading state is not accurately reflecting the form rendering process.
The loader never becomes true.
What I've tried:
Using nextTick to handle the loading state.
Ensuring the loader is shown when the component is mounted.
Desired Outcome:
Display a loader while the form is rendering in each tab and hide the loader once the form is fully rendered.
How can I accurately track the rendering process and manage the loading state to show the loader correctly?

If it's currentTab.value = that causes a freeze then await nextTick() should be used before it

Personally i use the following pattern to show loading states when waiting for api data to arrive.
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-if="loading">
            <!-- show loading spinner -->
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <!-- show component -->
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                loading: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submit(){
                this.loading = true;
                axios.post('/api/endpoint', {
                    // some data payload
                }).then((response) =>{
                    // handle response
                }).catch((error) => {
                    // handle error
                }).finally(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>

This might not be an exact answer to your question, but perhaps you can get something usefull out of it. Hope it helps, good luck!
